# Laravel Herd uninstall PHP version

Tags: php, laravel, macos, laravel-herd

At first, I installed PHP 8.2, but now I need to work with PHP 8.1, Now I installed both. I need to get rid of 8.2 because I haven't use it for too long and appealed to use 8.3 if I need to start another project.

How to uninstall the 8.2?

[image]

Answer (score 3):

#1: The best way is to [uninstall and install](https://herd.laravel.com/docs/1/troubleshooting/uninstalling) Herd and the php version you want.

#2: An alternative to uninstall a PHP version is by simply deleting the binaries from your `~/Library/Application Support/Herd/bin` folder. Just make sure that there is no FPM instance currently using this version/stop Herd before.
The main problem with "uninstalling" PHP version is that it's not as simple as it seems.
You could run `herd isolate 8.2` to isolate a specific site to always use PHP 8.2. If you would then delete PHP 8.2 this site would no longer work, which might be confusing. [Reference](https://github.com/beyondcode/herd-community/issues/69#issuecomment-1658039417)